# BulkInsert fails for knn_vector data type with mapper_parsing_exception

Tags: java, elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I am using BulkInsert (Java client) to ingest with an Index that has knn_vector Data Type. Currently, I am able to ingest when I create `document` with a POJO Class object for every row that insert into Index. I am using `List<Float>` in the POJO for the "Embeddings" column values to work.

I just want to dynamically read from a file (with header) and ingest into Indexes. I tried with `Map<Object, Object>` to create the `document` but it complains for the "embeddings" column. I want to check if I have a way to ingest without pre-creating the POJO Class?

Ex: POJO class

```
@Builder
@Data
Class MoviesIndex {
private String movieName, 
private String movieGenre, 
.
.
private List<Float> embeddings;
.
}
```

BulkInsert snippet

```
for (MoviePojo movie : movies) {
  bulkOps.add(
          new BulkOperation.Builder()
                  .index(IndexOperation.of(io -> io.index(indexName).document(movie)))
                  .build());
}
```